# Filtering based on a value from a different column but also from a different row

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, filtering, unique

I would like to filter values from "Column 1" if the corresponding value in "Column 2" is "B", but only if none of the identical (duplicate) values in Column 1 have a value of "A" in "Column 2".

To simplify, the output should be "2" and "4", since those are the only values that don't have a value of "A" in "Column 2" in any of their iterations in "Column 1".

I was able to do this in Excel using two dynamic formulas and XLOOKUP.

Via VBA I can do a For Each Loop that would filter all the values that have a value of "B" in Column 2 (in this case it would return all the values from "Column 1" except "3"), which isn't what I need.

```vb
Sub ChooseStatus()

Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
'defining the area
lr = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

sr = Selection.Row

'defining categories
Item = Sheet1.Cells(sr, 1)
Status = Sheet1.Cells(sr, 2)

'loop
For i = 2 To lr
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 2) = "B" Then
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = rgbBlue
    End If
Next i
   
End Sub
```

| Item | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 4 | B |
| 5 | A |
| 5 | B |

Comment: Hi @braX,

Thanks for reaching out. I have inserted the code I was working on (quite rudimentary, as I've been into VBA for a little more than 2 weeks), however, as mentioned, this isn't the result I'm actually seeking and I'm clueless as to how to get to it, I would like if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dispose of Excel version MS365 and its `UNIQUE()` function, you might try the following procedure `Examplecall` together with the user defined help functions `GetFormula()` and `IsValid()`. *(If not there are many examples at SO how to get unique values in versions before)*.

This approach demonstrates also the use of the following frequent VBA functions

- [Worksheet.Evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate)
- [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filter-function)
- [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function)
- [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function)

**Example call**

```
Option Explicit                 ' force declarations at code module head

Sub ExampleCall()

With Sheet1                     ' << change to wanted sheet Code(Name)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = .Range("A2:B11")  ' << change to wanted range (note the starting "."-point)
'a) get uniques array & provide for temporary results array
    Dim uniques
    uniques = .Evaluate(GetFormula(rng))
    Dim results
    results = uniques           ' contains temporarily all uniques
End With
'b) mark all invalid items for deletion
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(uniques)
        If Not IsValid(uniques, i) Then results(i) = "$DEL$"
    Next i
'c) remove marked items from results array
    results = Filter(results, "$DEL$", False)       ' negative filtering removes $DEL$ items
    MsgBox Join(results, vbNewLine), vbInformation, "Found elements"
End Sub
```

---

**Help functions**

```
Function GetFormula(rng As Range, Optional Delim As String = "-") As String
'a) define column number within the passed range argument
    Const ITEM As Long = 1, STATUS As Long = 2          '
    If rng.Columns.Count < Application.Max(ITEM, STATUS) Then Exit Function  ' provide for sufficient columns
'b) define formula pattern
    Dim Pattern As String
    Pattern = "transpose(Unique(X & """ & Delim & """ & Y))"            ' get unique combined strings
'c) replace range references X and Y with address string
    GetFormula = Replace(Replace(Pattern, _
        "X", rng.Columns(ITEM).Address(0, 0)), _
        "Y", rng.Columns(STATUS).Address(0, 0))
End Function
```

```
Function IsValid(uniques, no As Long, _
            Optional Exclude As String = "A", _
            Optional Delim As String = "-") As Boolean
'a) get prefix of element no (i.e. string part before hyphen)
    Dim ItemPrefix As String
    ItemPrefix = Split(uniques(no), "-")(0)             ' isolate string part before "-" via Split()
'b) filter items to be excluded
    Dim tmp
    tmp = Filter(uniques, ItemPrefix & Delim & Exclude, True)   ' positive filtering of term to be excluded
'c) if there are no found items then return True as function result
    If UBound(tmp) = -1 Then                            ' upper boundary -1 indicates empty 0-based array
        IsValid = True                                  ' return positive function result
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Wow - thanks so much. It doesn't just solve my problem, but it also opens a whole new world for me.